# Can't add an existing folder to Visual Studio 2012. "Include in Project" menu option is missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am running Visual Studio 2012 (administrator) in Windows 8. I am unable to add an existing folder using Solution Explorer. I also can't drag the folder from File Explorer into the Solution Explorer. I get the invalid target drop icon.

The only way I know is to add the folders by Add - "New Folder" and creating the folders manually.

Why am I am having these issues?

**Why is 'Include in Project' menu option missing?**
[image: s]

Comment: I'm looking for this too!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

"Include in Project" shows up for files only not folders. When files are includes, their folders get included.

Comment: That's not correct. Including a file in the project that is contained in a sub-folder does NOT automatically add the folder.

Comment: Yes it does! I included the file and its folder got included with it.

Comment: Ignore the erroneous advice from Tony_Henrich.

Comment: @Iucounu Just say it doesn't work for you! Maybe your VS is different. Maybe your VS or system are screwed up. It worked for me. Make sure VS shows all the files, right click on the file include it in the project and the file and its folder get included. it's your problem if it doesn't work for you. Tell people not to even try. Your advice is useless and does not good.

Comment: Well, Tony, I can confirm that it doesn't work for me, either.  If you right click on a file it does include that file, but the folder never shows up.

Answer (score 10):

Click the icon for "show all files" in Solution Explorer. You will then be able to see any pre-existing directories and include them in your project.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your project is not currently in debug mode.Stop the debugging mode and Right click on folder it will show the "Include in Project"

Comment: That was the real problem in my case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb.

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh LMFAO